# How is my Cantonese pronunciation of 汪阿姐?

Tags: pronunciation, cantonese

汪阿姐 wong1 aa3 ze1/ze2

https://recorder.google.com/share/834c05d1-6723-4465-a207-76778d8d9bab

Please upload your pronunciation audio and help identify what characters I pronounced incorrectly or imperfectly.

Comment: Try this App.  https://www.cantonesetools.org/en/cantonese-text-to-sound

Comment: the pause in the 1st try is too long, the 2nd one is natural, near perfect, imo 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

汪阿姐:  I feel you can enunciate your tone change a little more, the high vs middle tone feel a little too muddy, one 阿 seemed much lower suddenly and the tones weren't compeltely flat etc.  However it wasn't bad and I may feel differently if I actually heard you speak-- hearing someone say only two tones doesn't really help pick up their speech patterns or pronunciation on these things.

Overall if there was a context to expect you to say this I would likely recognize it.

I don't know how you would want audio uploaded but if it is something I can easily do on an iphone I'd be happy to

Comment: also welcome :)

Comment: Revisiting/reviewing this ... In general, https://recorder.google.com is a good tool to share audio snippets.